# Connect two users to internet with one wired socket

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, wired-networking

I am a university student, and I live at a student hall. My student hall, does not have WiFi, (and does not allow someone to install a router), and I only have a socket to connect to the internet by a wire.

A friend of mine will come in two days, to do a project together, and we will both need access to the internet. We both have Windows 8 installed. This is for just a couple of hours.

How I am able to connect both computers at the network with having only one socket? Is it possible to do that, but without being able for the student hall to see that I have connected two laptops?

I will just need it for a couple of hours.

***Edit***

Using the solution from [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/112050/how-to-turn-your-windows-8-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/) does not work for me. When I try to make my connection shared, then automatically my wired connection shows a "limited conenctivity" symbol, and I cannot connect at the Internet. Do I make any mistake? Is there any alternative?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Warning in regards to Lee Harrison's answer: In his answer, the second paragraph's assumptions can get students penalized and/or fined. Even without the SSID being broadcast, the router verifying its existence with upstream devices is a common red flag and is regularly monitored. I've had the unfortunate displeasure of issuing warnings.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what the rules you have to follow are. You say you're not allowed to "install a router". Does that include wired routers? Does that include other devices, such as computers, acting as routers?

Comment: I agree with Zach. It would especially be common to monitor these in settings where use of "rogue" routers is expected - such as student dormitories. Depends on network administrators and implementation of policies.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks for your comment. I think they do not specify, but instead they generalise. I just want to find a solution firstly that it works, and then to find out if it's comply with their rules or not

Comment: @JimBlum Well, a WiFi router works very, very well, and they cost [around $10](http://www.wirelessoemshop.com/servlet/the-1693/Netgear-Wireless-G-Router/Detail?gclid=COaa3tXwg7wCFVFgfgodsQQARw) and are incredibly handy to have around.

Comment: @DavidSchwart Thanks a lot. I will have this in mind. But Is it possible to do it using only my computer?

Comment: @JimBlum Yes, a computer can do pretty much anything a router can do. Punch `ICS` into your favorite search engine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It doesn't work. As soon as I enable sharing as mentioned by JSanchez below, I gen limited or no connectivity at my host... I cannot find a solution about that...

Comment: The trouble with using your computer is that you have to know a few bits about it. I assume you know because you seem to have some programming background. My experience with windows is that often there is some poorly documented obscure thing with networking why there are failures and you have to go through step by step tickboxes like you do now and then still wonder what it is you are doing "wrong". in my experience linux is a lot more straightforward and educational. And nearly every router will run linux, and you will likely be able to use macchanger.

Comment: Another option - depending on how powerful your laptop is - run Linux on it and route all things through it, and run your copy of windows in a virtualbox virtual machine on laptop, if you need windows ;)

Answer (score 4):

[How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/112050/how-to-turn-your-windows-8-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/) has provided a nice, step-by-step tutorial on how to use your Windows 8 laptop as a wireless access point.

Comment: Thanks a lot JSanchez. This is what I had in mind, but is it able to do that, without my student hall to be able to recognize that I have installed two pcs at the network? In addition, as I only have one IP (I think), is it possible for both computers to use only that IP?

Comment: Using this tutorial, you're essentially using your laptop as a WiFi router.  All traffic will come from a single IP tied to your laptop, and depending on how much sniffing they're doing on the network they may be able to tell that you have a "router".

Comment: @heavyd thanks a lot for your answer. If we both make a few search at wikipedia, or google search how they are able to find that out?

Comment: @JimBlum: Because you're sharing your Internet connection, all traffic will seem as if it comes from your one device. Of course, if they're doing further filtering, they will detect that another device is piggyback riding on your one connection. Doubtful, but not impossible to rule out. The thing you have to keep in mind is: what are the repercussions for violating their TOS policy?

Comment: Exactly my point - it is possible to find out with traffic analysis. Mind you that if you just wish to have a local network in your dorm room, you do not need to share the internet connection to your laptop.  Or you can equally share internet coming through your mobile phone, if signal is decent and you have unlimited traffic, AND your data usage is reasonably low.

Comment: Hi. I have just tried that solution. At the step where I make my connection shared, my host cannot connect either. Why is that? and how I can fix that?

Comment: Did you do all the steps in the tutorial? There are steps that will turn on the shared connection. And you turned on the shared connection on the wireless connection, right?

Comment: @JSanchez yes... I tried all of them. I could even see the new networks name at my mobile phone. But the connection was still limited...

Comment: @JSanchez any new ideas?

Comment: @JimBlum: Stop/Start the Internet Connection Sharing service. Start->Run (sorry, I don't have Win8) then type services.msc and click OK. Find Internet Connection Sharing and stop and start that service.

Comment: hmmm... does not help at all...

Comment: From the command prompt, type "devmgmt.msc" and hit Enter. Find a "virtual something or other" device under "Network Adapters" Right click it, and if you see "Enable" in the pop-up, click it. Then run "netsh wlan start hostednetwork" from the command line. Let us know what happens then.

Comment: @JSanchez No virtual to me...

Comment: Under "services.msc" see if "Routing and Remote Access" is started

Comment: I thought he said he's not allowed to use a router. If he's using his computer as a router, isn't it at that point a router -- the very thing he's not allowed to use?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions available, but all will have **two features in common**.

1. There will be a computer with at least 2 network interfaces e.g. ethernet and WiFi or USB (for the latter you may need a bridge adapter and specific network drivers).
2. That computer will serve as a NAT router for the other computer(s) connecting through that.

So technically you cannot avoid situation where you are creating a router because you are sharing `one` network socket/input. You cannot use some sort of network splitter as this will create all sorts of problems, and will be very obvious, not least due to requiring occupying 2 ports on the switch (from which you get that Ethernet lead).

Having acknowledged that your choice is between the solution proposed by JSanchez where you use your laptop as a router and you friend's laptop connects through that, or using any of the very portable travel [routers](http://lifehacker.com/five-best-travel-routers-1452441479) where both your friend's and you computer connects through that little box.

For network operators to detect a NAT router is not a very trivial task and you can see it is described [here](http://www.sflow.org/detectNAT/).

Answer (score 1):

Just get a very small hub and connect the PCs to it. I highly doubt your hall has someone monitoring port traffic. Connect the wall to the #5 port, and the two PCs to any other two ports.

[image]
[http://www.amazon.com/NETGEAR-ProSAFE-5-Port-Ethernet-Desktop/dp/B00002EQCW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00002EQCW)

I've got one of these in my AV cabinet and it works great. The only downside is it's not Gigabit but I don't move that much data either. Since your not transmitting a WiFi signal, there is really no easy way for someone to realize you are doing this.

Of course another option would be to say screw you to your student hall and buy a wifi router anyway. Just setup your SSID so that it is 'hidden' and clients cannot autodiscover it unless the explicitly type in the name. Then you can have WiFi, but no one will really know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot to mention that as it is just for a very few times, I do not want to buy any device... Can this be done with our computers as they are?

Comment: I'd point out that the dorm I lived in did MAC address filtering, so devices all had to be registered with the network.

Comment: @ernie good to know, I had never heard of a campus being that restricted! And apologies to the OP, I thought this could become a more long term deal

Comment: hmmm... This possibly is done here as well... So What I can do to connect the two laptops if my dorm has also MAC address filtering? @ernie

Comment: No, it was my mistake @LeeHarrison :) This could be also a very good option, (and therefore I will upvote your answer, as soon as I get 15 reputation because I cannot vote now) but as we are collaborating more at the university, my classmates will come at my room very few times. So I am trying to avoid buying devices if there are any software alternatives.

Comment: It is possible to find out NAT routers on local network from traffic patterns (see reference in my answer), but someone has to bother enough to do that.  You can use just your laptop and share it's WiFi. Mind you that most decent devices and certainly linux computers have the possibility to present their MAC as a different one (e.g. your laptop's) - so when you are fed up with sharing WiFi via your laptop, you can install one of the router devices once you have told it what MAC to show.

Comment: Of course - "hidden" WiFi SSIDs can be found out easily - just with software. Reference here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_cloaking